# Как мне вывести сообщение "пользователь заблокирован" на странице логина в java spring security?

Tags: javascript, html, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Всем привет. Мне нужно выводить сообщение на форме логина, если пользователь имеет статус BANNED. Я думал брать данные из инпутов, с помощью метода пост, но spring security берёт данные из них первой, а затем обнуляет их. Можно ли как-то их до этого перехватить или есть другой способ получше? Если можно, то с примером, пожалуйста

### Контроллер авторизации AuthController.java

```
    @Controller
@RequestMapping("/auth")
public class AuthController {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public AuthController(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    protected PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(12);
    }


    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String getLoginPage(Model model,
                               @RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String error,
                               @RequestParam(value = "logout", required = false) String logout) {
        if (checkAuth()) {
            return "redirect:/index";
        }

        if (error != null) {
            model.addAttribute("error", "Неправильное имя пользователя или пароль!");
        }

        if (logout != null) {
            model.addAttribute("logout", "Вы вышли!");
        }
        return "login";
    }

    private boolean checkAuth() {
        return SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal() instanceof User;
    }
}
```

### Форма логина login.html

```
    <body align="center">


<form method="post" action="/auth/login">
    <h2>Вход</h2>
    <div class="text-danger" th:text="${error}">...</div>
    <div th:text="${logout}">...</div>
    <p>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="E-mail" required>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Пароль" required>
    </p>
    <button class="dropbtn" type="submit">Войти</button>
</form>

<a href="/auth/registration">Зарегистрироваться</a>

</body>
```

### Класс User.java

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "role")
    private Role role;

    @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "status")
    private Status status;
```

Ссылка на гитхаб: https://github.com/aposternak35/to-do-list-master

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем всё оказалось куда проще. В SecurityConfig начал вызывать пост метод через .failureForwardUrl, вместо .failureUrl и сообщения стали нормально выводиться, если кому интересно решение, ссылка на гит: https://github.com/aposternak35/to-do-list-master . Там кривая приложенька туду лист и авторизация с аутефикацией, в качестве БД подключал MySQL.